# How to Tab List Items Cyclically

Tags: javascript, html, tabs, navigation, accessibility

I am trying to make tabbing cyclical within a dropdown menu.

Here's my JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Lc7saks3/

```
<nav id="primary_nav_wrap">
  <div>
    <ul>
      <li tabindex="0"><a href="#">Menu</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Option 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Option 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Option 3</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Option 4</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Option 5</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>  
  </div>
  <br />
  <br />  
  <input type="text" />
</nav>
```

Click on the Menu element and then tab through the options.

Currently, the tabbing goes through the 5 options within the dropdown menu and then moves on to the input element.

> How can I make it such that the dropdown options are tabbed again,
>   cyclically, from option 1, once the last option (option 5) is reached?

Answer (score 1):

You would need to use script [listen for the Tab key](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/javascript-keycodes/) while [on the last item](https://davidwalsh.name/focused-element) and, when pressed, immediately [move focus](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/focus) back to the first item (or dynamically adjust `tabindex` values when you get to the last item).

However, **DO NOT DO THIS** as it constitutes a keyboard trap and is a failure of WCAG 2.0 item 2.1.2, [No Keyboard Trap](https://www.w3.org/WAI/WCAG20/quickref/?showtechniques=212#keyboard-operation-trapping). There is a lengthy technique for handling this that essentially says to not do what you are trying to do: [G21: Ensuring that users are not trapped in content](https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/G21.html)

Finally, I suggest you take the `tabindex` off the `li` as that is not an interactive / actionable control and no place for a `tabindex`.